# php mysqli prepared statement: can't echo, print or get anything from var_dump AFTER execute command

Tags: php, mysqli

I am starting to use mysqli and I got it working on my virtual server but can't get it working on my real server. The databases are the same. I have tried both store and get_result. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Everything I try to echo, print or var_dump does not show up IF Place after execute but the command will be executed. It worked well on UPDATE and INSERT.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "pass", "db", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  }

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$sam = 1;


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT released FROM svers");
$stmt->execute();
echo "#";
var_dump($sam);
$res = $stmt->get_result();

var_dump($res);

$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
var_dump($row);


$mysqli->close();
```

The host_info is displayed as "127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP" followed By the # I echoed inside the if() but can't get anything from my database. Even the other # between the $row[ ] info are not showing. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "user", "password", "database", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
  }

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM svers ORDER BY released DESC LIMIT 1");

if ($result = $stmt->execute()){
    echo "#";
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    echo $row['version'] . "#" . $row['released'] . "#" . $row['note'];
    $stmt->free_result();
}else {
    echo "error";
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: Because, you're not quering and have nothing "to" prepare. So change `prepare` to `query` or slap a query in there. Read up on prepared statements http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php - Be sure to check for errors also http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Be sure to hide your username/passwords on forums in the future.

Comment: Changed it to query and didn't help. And thanks for the pass and username info. Hide them in the start but had to copy past the code again and forgot to do it again :-)

Comment: Read the manual(s) from the links I gave you above.

Comment: 'var_dumb' - I love this misspelling :D

Comment: That was real helpful! cheers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem solved. My real server didn't support mysqlnd so can't use get_result(). Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Facing the same problem .Can you tell me please how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying `got it working on my virtual server but can't get it working on my real server`.

Then check `svers` table on real server contains any data.

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this "answer"?

Comment: Yes as i see no fault in prepared statement as he is not binding any parameter.

Comment: It has the same data and names. It does work well on my virtual server. I just don't get it why doesn't it return anything from the rows.

Comment: @Mikko What you get from var_dump($result); in real server?

Comment: Also in my environment all the three # are outputted even though no data in the table

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply. I did try the var_dump but it doesn't give me anything if Place it after the execute() command. For example the variable $sam does show up at var_dump if placed before execute command. However nothing will be echoed or printed after the execute command. The query will get executed. I tried to INSERT and UPDATE and they worked just fine on the real server.

Comment: Have you tried by replacing `$mysqli->prepare` with  `$mysqli->query`. In later case you won't need to call `execute()`

Comment: Yes. By doing that everthing will be printed till get_result(); after that nothing.